# What is the difference between ViewState,Application and Session of a Page?

Tags: asp.net

Please anyone explain me the difference between ViewState,Application and Session of a Page ?

Comment: Neither is good for your web application.

Comment: @Adrian this is similar between them :), not difference.

Comment: Yes..., I just can't stand to comment. :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application vs Session vs Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096544/application-vs-session-vs-cache)

Comment: @AdrianGodong Why is neither good? What are your suggested alternatives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick one liners - if you want more detail, just ask

ViewState is the variable that holds the current state of the page, which is held in a hidden field in the page (used frequently)

ApplicationState is a variable you can store values in during the life off the application (may get cycled periodically, and without your knowledge) (used less-frequently)

Session is the variable you can write to that will persist from the moment they hit your site until they close the browser. (barring any timeouts). (used frequently)

Comment: Additionaly: the scope of ViewState is the page (and only for postbacks), for Session it's the session (single user) and for AppState it's global, for all users.

Comment: Technically, Session lasts until the timeout period is reached with no further activity, not when the browser is closed. The server has no way to know when the user closes the browser.

Answer (score 7):

A great article :
[How to Choose From Viewstate, Session, Application, Cache, and Cookies](http://www.articlesbase.com/programming-articles/how-to-choose-from-viewstate-session-application-cache-and-cookies-443393.html)

Some good discussion about the difference between Session and Viewstate : [Session Vs ViewState](http://forums.asp.net/p/886104/1355584.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Session** state is saved on the server.
Session state is usually cleared after a period of inactivity from the user.
Can be persisted in memory, which makes it a fast solution. Which means state cannot be shared in the Web Farm/Web Garden.
Can be persisted in a Database, useful for Web Farms / Web Gardens.
Is Cleared when the session dies - usually after 20min of inactivity.

**ViewState** is saved in the page.
The view state is posted on subsequent post back in a hidden field.
Is sent back and forth between the server and client, taking up bandwidth.
Has no expiration date.
Is useful in a Web Farm / Web Garden

Answer (score 1):

SESSION Variables are stored on the server, can hold any type of data including references, they are similar to global variables in a windows application and use HTTP cookies to store a key with which to locate user's session variables.

VIEWSTATE Variables are stored in the browser (not as cookies) but in a hidden field in the browser. Also Viewstate can hold only string data or serializable objects.

Answer (score 1):

When we use view state to design a web application it retains it's state consistently, in it's current position. If we use session then it does not retain it's state, so when we refresh the browser it starts from the initial page.