# ASP.NET Application Object Getters and Setters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, getter-setter

I have had a hard time finding a newbie friendly example of accessing the Application Object. I have few things ( arrays ) I would like to store in the Application Object to keep as persistent data for about 2 hours until AppRecycle.

Anyhow, I know how to set an Application Object variable this way:

```
// One way
String[] users = new String[1000];
Application["users"] = users;

// Another way
Application.Add("users", users);
```

However I do not know how to access these variables once they are inside the Application Object. There is a Getter method `Get`. However it requires `int index`. The other method, `Contents`, get's everything, not just my array.

Here I try to retrieve my String[] array, but it gives me a error that I am trying to convert Object to String.

```
String[] usersTable = Application["users"];
// Since this is an object i also tried Application.users but gives error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Application you only save type "object". You need to cast to the desired type

```
string[] usersTable = (string[])Application["users"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the value back to `String[]`:

```
String[] usersTable = (String[])Application["users"];
```

See How to: [Read Values from Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8hhek39%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First I suggest for your case to simple use a static variable on the string

```
static String[] users = new String[1000];
```

and manipulate that. Is better than Application state. [What Microsoft says about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net/10964038#10964038):

> ASP.NET includes application state primarily for compatibility with
>   classic ASP so that it is easier to migrate existing applications to
>   ASP.NET. **It is recommended that you store data in static members** of
>   the application class instead of in the Application object. This
>   increases performance because you can access a static variable faster
>   than you can access an item in the Application dictionary.

Now if you continue to use the Application I strongly suggest to use use `Application.Lock();` and `Application.UnLock();`  when you manipulate the data of the Application and your code will be as:

```
String[] _users = null;
String[] users
{
    get
    {
        if (_users == null)
        {
            Application.Lock();
            if (!(Application["_users_"] is String[]))
            {
                Application["_users_"] = new String[1000];
            }
            _users = (String [])Application["_users_"];
            Application.UnLock();
        }

        return _users;
    }
}
```

#### Why I suggest to simple use a static ?

Because the `Application["_users_"]` is actually a call to a static `Dictionary<k,v>` that store among other data, and the data you set as String[]. No actually reason to make that, a  static can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution, IMO, would be use the WebCache (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d59zceh7.aspx) due to the amount of control you can have over expiration and dependencies. This way, if you had the desire to no longer recylce your app-pool, you could still keep the data for a limited, set period of time.

```
         string[] Cache["users"];
```

That's all you need to access the cache for your object. Setting it is easy as well. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add(v=vs.100).aspx