# Site wide global flag that can be set via HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I have a few configuration flags that I want to be able to set on/off via an http call (similar to a REST call).

Normally you store configuration settings in the web.config, or you pull things our from a file into a class, and this configuration class that you use throughout your application code is used as if it a singleton class or constants.

There is one property that I want to be able to modify at runtime, and this is a global variable.  Any modifications will be done by a single user or thread, and will occurr very rarely.

How should I design this and where should I store this?

My application code calls the Twitter API, but I want to be able to switch on/off if I should call the twitter API (it could be down), where should I store this on/off property knowing that I want to be able to update this field?

```
if(SomeClass.TwitterApiEnabled) 
{
   // call twitter api
}
```

I could toggle the TwitterApiEnabled property on/off using:

```
http://www.example.com/api/twitter/enable=no&auth_token=123
```

Comment: Have you tried a `static` field?

Comment: For one working process on the pool you can use ether static, ether cache, for more working process (web garden) you need to save it to a file/database

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only sensible way to store this would be storing this to a database / file in some manner as storing this in memory would mean on re-boot that the setting is lost.

Why not save a file call TwitterDisabled and when this is present twitter is disabled. Shouldn't really affect performance of you cache this per user session.

Answer (score 0):

1) Application variable -- these are global variables stored in a key/value pair 
Application["TwitterIsUp"] = isTwitterUp;

you'll need to cast it to get it out...

return (bool) Application["TwitterIsUp"];

2) Static field

Comment: The application variables are nothing more than a static Dictionary.

Comment: That are updatable and readable globally.  Sometimes, that's all you need.

Comment: As any static variable. Read about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net/10964038#10964038  Microsoft says: ASP.NET includes application state primarily for compatibility with classic ASP