# Is it possible to save information for all users for a webpage

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to save information for all users for a webpage in asp.net?
At the moment every User get a online list dynamicly every 10 seconds - so on 200 Users this will be 10x6x200 = 12000 database querys a minute.
But all Users going to have the same information at this time.

Is it possible to save the onlinelist every 10 seconds in somethin like a global location, something like a session but not per User, i will have this for all users - and only save this 10 seconds so the first call after 10 seconds refreshes the information?!

Comment: [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx) is shared across all requests.

Comment: So when I write the user table in the Cache.object for the first request in 10 seconds, all other requests will have access to it and share it? From every website?

Comment: The [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx) is application specific. So if _every website_ means for diffferent appclications the answer is no. If _website_ instead means _page_ the answer is yes.

Comment: With website I mean the aspx-sites in my web-application, sorry.

Comment: So can you write a few lines HwoTo Code as answer?

Comment: Is it something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net

Comment: Have a look at msdn, there are many examples. You could set [`absoluteExpiration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx) to `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)`.

Comment: you can use cache or Applicatio state