# Public Static Multi-User Variables

Tags: php, variables, static, public, multi-user

I'm currently working on a website where I have a couple variables that need to be shared across all users/sessions. The website is primarily built with HTML and PHP.

I know I can accomplish this task (storing multiuser/multisession variables) with APC, but the host I'm using (1and1) doesn't allow APC to be installed. Is there a way of storing these variables with just PHP, or just JavaScript? What about ASP?

Comment: Why tag a question about PHP as ASP.NET?

Comment: You can do it in ASP.NET with Application State. Looks like you've got some learning to do.  Good Luck!   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87316/A-walkthrough-to-Application-State

Comment: Do NOT use application state: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net/10964038#10964038