# Store data in memory which can be access from all users asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I store data in memory of asp.net mvc application which can be accessed by all users logged in.

Comment: that's part of the question - essentially want to store it in RAM, not DB storage. Essentially HttpContext.Current.Application variable that should be common for all users, but not sure if that's the best approach....

Comment: Data will anyways be stored in RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static variable. If you have some static Constants class, just create a static list or a static variable.

```
public static List<string> commonList =  new List<string>
```

Comment: Is that better approach compared to Application variables?

Comment: according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960695/using-static-variables-instead-of-application-state-in-asp-net) answer, Yes. It also gives reference to Microsoft support link which explains it.

Comment: thanks for the further details, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in your application using something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Application["somevar"] = "0";
}
```

Comment: I guess I should do locking as this is common resource for all users?

Comment: @LyubomirVelchev:- Indeed you can by using the Application variable your all users can use the variable value once the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will work for me:

```
Application.Lock();
Application["PageRequestCount"] = 
    ((int)Application["PageRequestCount"])+1;
Application.UnLock();
```

Here I can save data from user and store it in a data object which will be in application - stored in memory.
My idea is to make a chat, but not use a db, relying solely on RAM.
So every user will have their messages in their own session, when the user want to submit a message, it will lock and save in messages collection common for all users and the unlock. When the user read - there will be no need for unlocking. Just elaborating about possible use of that, but the answer of the question is the 3 lines source code.