# Application state staying longer than needed

Tags: c#, asp.net

From what I understand about application states, they are meant to be cleared out when the application has stopped. When I restart my ASP.NET application the data stored in the application state is still there for a few minutes.

Does anyone know why this is? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096544/application-vs-session-vs-cache) help?

Comment: @jsve Unfortunately not. I understand what the application state is supposed to do. It just isn't doing that.