# How to put data from one form into a listbox in another

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay so I'm adapting a C# program to an asp program and I have a main form which contains a list box and another which adds new information to the list box. I can fill in the 2nd form and hold values in `Application["getData"];` but when I go to the other page I need to run the following code.

```
public void AddGig()
    {
        AddGigForm frm = new AddGigForm();

        if (Application["getData"] != null)
        {
            Application["saveData"] = Application["getData"];
            gigList.addGig(frm.GetData());


            UpdateListbox();
        }
```

I run into problems at `gigList.addGig` as it goes back to the method `GetData()` on the 2nd form. I just have no idea what else to use.

GetData method:

```
public GigOpportunity GetData()
    {


            Application["GetData"] = new GigOpportunity
                (txtId.Text, gigDate.SelectedDate, txtVenue.Text, txtGenre.Text,
                Convert.ToDouble(txtCost.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacity.Text), chkHeadliner.Checked, txtMainAct.Text, chkEngineer.Checked);


            return new GigOpportunity(txtId.Text, gigDate.SelectedDate, txtVenue.Text, txtGenre.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtCost.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacity.Text), chkHeadliner.Checked, txtMainAct.Text, chkEngineer.Checked);
    }
```

addGig method:

```
public void addGig(GigOpportunity gigOpportunity)
    {
        //Make sure a gig with this id does not already exist

        foreach (GigOpportunity g in gigList)
        {
            if (g.GigId == gigOpportunity.GigId)
            {
                throw new DuplicateIdException();
            }
        }

        gigList.Add(gigOpportunity);
    }
```

Comment: What is AddGigForm? The best way to use data through pages is to use `Session` object for the current user not `Apllication` object as for all session they will share the same data.

Comment: AddGigForm is the 2nd form I use which has the fields used to add another gig to the 1st form. Is there any problem with using `application`?

Comment: I am not sure to understand well, `gigList` is it another list? And `addGig` could you show the code for this method. When you create the object AddGigForm, you can't retrieve data from it also. As it is a new object. And where do you call this method? Could you paste the all code if possible of this class.

Comment: gigList is a List, sure I'll add it to the question and I call gigList.addGig from GigOpportunity class, I'll post that method too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand now your problem. You musn't think like in windows form. You declared those method inside other form. When you call it by assigning a new Form object you will not get the value inside as they have been disposed after you change the page.

So in your case:

```
  if (Application["getData"] != null)
  {
        Application["saveData"] = Application["getData"];
        gigList.addGig((GigOpportunity)Application["getData"]);


        UpdateListbox();
  }
```

But I will suggest you to use `Session` object instead of `Application` object.
You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096544/application-vs-session-vs-cache)

So you have to do like this:

```
  if (Session["getData"] != null)
  {
        Session["saveData"] = Session["getData"];
        gigList.addGig((GigOpportunity)Session["getData"]);


        UpdateListbox();
  }
```

You don't need to create the second form object `AddGigForm` and you must be sure to call your method`GetData` in the form where is it declared to assign your Session.

Comment: Wow thank you it worked! I realise the problem was gigList.addGig(Whatever) I just didn't know what I need to put inside. I think I may use sessions after being advised to by a few people now. Thanks again