# Data over more than one Session

Tags: c#, session, iis

we have a strange problem, probably you can give me a Hint, because I've never seen something like this. We're using a WebApplication, where the Users log in with WIF. The problem looks like this:

1. User 1 uploads File1 with a self-created Upload-Control --> Works
2. User 2 uploads File2 with the same Control --> Upload fails after the File is uploaded, File2 stays in the Upload-Folder
3. User 3 uploads File3, but the UploadControl uses the Filename of User 2 --> Ooops

This means user 3 uploads File2, since this is still in the Upload-Folder and anyhow, the user3-Session knows the Filename of User 2.

My question: How is this possible: It seems like each user has his Unique Session ID, and as far as I know the HTTPContext lives only for the Request-Time, and we get the FileName from there.

It seems like this problem wasn't there since the beginning of the Control-usage, so I guess there is a Environment-change?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I did as Kununk said and use Sessions instead of Applications, but it seems like on some  HttpContext.Current.Session is null.

I checked the [What should I do if the current ASP.NET session is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null) and implemented IRequiresSessionState on our IHttpHandler, but it does not work still. 
Furthermore I implemented the AcquireRequestState-Event and this is called for sure.

Is there any other possibility why the Session is null?

Comment: with code samples I could help more :) I would speculate on usage of static fields in the classes for settings stuff in the upload control, but that's just guessing due to limited information.

Comment: It's really hard to show code, since this UploadControl is quite big and the Code, which causes the problem is not ours.
BUT: We have a Singleton Class, but this one reads the relevant Data of the Request as well:
return HttpContext.Current.Application[STATUS_KEY + key] as UploadStatus;

Comment: what about HttpContext.Current.Session? Application is like a static class

Comment: So you say, if the STATUS_KEY + key would fit on x Users, they would get the same Data? Sadly I did not create the Control, is there a reason for Application over Session?

Comment: Application is per server, Session is per user. You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096544/application-vs-session-vs-cache

Comment: Thank you sir, I guess this might be a good explenation