# Session Variable across multiple solutions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, dotnetnuke

I have a website created on DotNetNuke. the pages are all independent solution files kept together under one directory. Now when i need to make any changes, I have to open that particular solution, make changes and then build only that. And then run the website from the main solution.
Now i want to use a session variable across all the solution file to get the IP of the user and based on that show all pages.
can the session variable be used here? or any other approach is required.

Comment: Instead of `Session` you can use `Application` perhaps. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096544/application-vs-session-vs-cache. DNN also has it's own caching mechanism. But I do not know if it is shared between portals.

Comment: Or is there any way i can write the method at some common place and then all the solution files can refer it adding a reference or Application variable.