# Is there a replacement for `HttpApplicationtState` in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating a legacy application written in Asp.Net MVC framework to ASP.net core MVC and some classes use `HttpApplicationState` to share cache object between all the users of the app

I've tried to read online about a replacement for this object (like `IFormFile` replacing `HttpPostedFile`) but could not find any information regarding this object

```
/* This method being called from the global.asax file in framework app and 
   usses the HttpApplicationState  */
public static void Foo(HttpApplicationState app)
{
   app.Set("Cache", cache);
}
```

I would like to know how can i achieve a similar behavior in my migrated application

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is very simple.

First, know that the `HttpApplicationState` object stores data [for all users and sessions to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096659/16052696), quote "**Unlike session state, which is specific to a single user session, application state applies to all users and sessions.**".

Therefore, you can look at the `HttpApplicationState` object as a basic caching object that is shared across all.

**So to answer your question**, the replacement for the `HttpApplicationState` object is:

- [`IMemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which could be the literal replacement of `HttpApplicationState` if you want to replicate (more or less) the legacy application
- [`IDistributedCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which is much more recommended nowadays

Answer (score 0):

You can add a singleton in the DI container:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ClassToStoreData>();
}
```

After this you can access the data by adding this parameter to the constructor of any class:

```
public class SomeClassThatUsesCache
{
    public SomeClassThatUsesCache(ClassToStoreData cache)
    {

    }
}
```

The data inside ClassToStoreData will be available to all users and any place in your application

Comment: The problem with this solution is that i would need to convert all of the classes in the app to instantiated through the DI and i was hoping to avoid this kind of massive refactor (yes its an old app, 2010 old)

Comment: You can use a static class that has a reference to the ClassToStoreData which is set in the Configure method of your startup but I would not recommend it.